# \n and \r's different behaviors under different circumstances in Vim

Tags: vim

Say I have a line with just a character 's', let's go see `\n`'s effect under different circumstances:

```
:s/s/a\nb
a^@b
:s/s/a\\nb
a\nb
:s/s/a\\\nb
a\^@b
:s/s/a\\\\nb
a\\nb

:echo "a\nb"
a
b
:echo "a\\nb"
a\nb
:echo "a\\\nb"
a\
b
:echo "a\\\\nb"
a\\nb
```

So why does `\n` behave differently? Then let's see the condition using `substitute()`

```
:echo substitute(" ", " ", "a\nb", "")
a
b
:echo substitute(" ", " ", "a\\nb", "")
a
b
:echo substitute(" ", " ", "a\\\nb", "")
a
b
:echo substitute(" ", " ", "a\\\\nb", "")
a\nb
```

This time, `\n` is still interpreted as "newline", but how to explain the backslash?

Next part, say I still have a line with just a character 's', instead of `\n`, `\r` is going to be studied:

```
:s/s/a\rb
a
b
:s/s/a\\rb
a\rb
:s/s/a\\\rb
a\
b
:s/s/a\\\\rb
a\\rb
```

`\r`'s effect is like `\n` in `:echo "a\nb"`, and the rule of backslash is the same.

```
:echo "a\rb"
b
:echo "a\\rb"
a\rb
:echo "a\\\rb"
b\  "This is the most strange case!!!
:echo "a\\\\rb"
a\\rb
```

What does `\r` do in this case? And the third subcase is even stranger.

```
:echo substitute(" ", " ", "a\rb", "")
b
:echo substitute(" ", " ", "a\\rb", "")
b
:echo substitute(" ", " ", "a\\\rb", "")
b
:echo substitute(" ", " ", "a\\\\rb", "")
a\rb
```

Still, I cannot understand how different number of backslashes behave.

My question are:

1. Why does `\n` or `\r` behave differently under `:substitute`、 `echo` directly and `substitute()`?
2. How to explain different number of backslashes' effect when using `substitute()`?
3. What are the differences between `\n` and `\r` in Vim?

Supplement 1:

if I `:let s = "a\\\nb"` and then `<C-r>=s` to see it in the buffer, I see

```
a\
        b
```

How to explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For both `:echo` and `substitute()`, `\n` is a newline and `\r` is a carriage return. They should do what you would expect. `\n` moves the cursor to the next line (column 1), and `\r` moves the cursor to column 1 same line. For `\r` the next character that gets printed will overwrite the previously print character. (I'm mostly focused on `substitute()` and `:echo`, `:substitute` is below)
2. For why echo and substitute() behave differently. You need to understand how many interpretations of the string are happening. For echo only one happens for substitute() two happen.

   ```
   :echo substitute(" ", " ", "a\\\rb", "")
   b
   :echo substitute(" ", " ", 'a\\\rb', "")
   b\
   ```

The second is the same as what you would have expected for echo. 
Strings in double quotes have there contents changed according to `:help expr-quote`. This means that both echo and substitute see the same thing if the string is only interpreted once (which is using single quotes)

`"a\\\rb"` gets interpreted as `a\rb` after one interpretation and then `a<CR>b` after the second. Which leads to only `b` getting printed.

3. `\r` and `\n` change depending on where they are used. The only difference would be `:substitute` where `\r` is used as a newline in the replacement.

---

This is one of the cases where `:substitute` and `substitute()` behave differently,

`:substitue` follows

```
  <CR>        split line in two at this point
              (Type the <CR> as CTRL-V <Enter>)                  s<CR>
  \r          idem                                               s/\r
  ...
  \n          insert a <NL> (<NUL> in the file)
              (does NOT break the line)                          s/\n
```

(`<NUL>` is the same as `^@` which is not the same as a newline)

while `substitute()` follows

```
The special meaning is also used inside the third argument {sub} of
the substitute() function with the following exceptions:
...
  - <CR> and \r inserts a carriage-return (CTRL-M).
...
```

Comment: Awesome answer! I almost get it. Consider `:echo substitute(" ", " ", "a\\\rb", "")`, why does `"a\\\rb"` get interpreted as `a\rb` after one interpretation? Is this interpretation due to `substitute()`? Shouldn't it be `a\^Mb` after one interpretation?

Comment: @fujianjin6471 It is. But the meaning of `\^M` is mostly undefined. From `:h /\\` A backslash followed by a single character, with no special meaning, is reserved for future expansions. Currently `\^M` gets interpreted as a carriage return. You can see this if you place `^M` in the buffer (`<C-v><CR>`) and then search for `/\^M`. And see that `^M` gets matched. (Don't depend on this behavior)

Comment: Thanks, but if I `:let s = "a\\\nb"`and then `<C-r>=s` to see it in the buffer, I see something really unexplainable. I show it in the question.

Comment: @fujianjin6471 I see `a\<NL>b` where `<NL>` is a newline (`a\ ` on the first line and `b` on the second). Thats whats expected. You don't see the slash in  `:echo substitute(" ", " ", "a\\\rb", "")` because substitute does its own interpretation of the escape codes (after the normal string escape codes are translated). Let does not do this and neither does the expression register.

Comment: @fujianjin6471 I don't see what you see in the edit when I type that into vim.

Comment: @fujianjin6471 Actually that can happen if you have some sort of auto indentation feature on since the characters added by the expression register act as if they were typed manually (I think). See if you have something with a filetype it might come with an indentexpr that does this or you might have some other setting on.

Comment: You are right! The reason I see the output in update is due to `set cindent`